# Is there an API to draw a B-TREE?

Tags: java, user-interface, b-tree

That's a simple question: is there an API to draw a [B-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) in Java? I just dont want to spend much time reinventing the wheel. I am not having trouble with the algorithm *per si*, mine works perfectly fine after a lot of reading (specially Lafore's Data Structures & Algorithms in Java), I just dont know how to print a B-tree in a good way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can easily generate Graphviz code directly which you can then feed into Graphviz. No need for the API. See http://ysangkok.github.io/js-clrs-btree/btree.html (push *init simple*)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got a couple of options to "render" a graph to screen -

- Graphviz has a Java API (Edit: an addon called LJV which gives the API).
- I think you ought to be able to use the free version of JGraph to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

I know people have had success with daVinci (now [uDraw](http://www.informatik.uni-bremen.de/uDrawGraph/en/index.html)). I haven't used it since 2003, but from what I remember, you have to generate a bracketed text file for your tree and the program parses it. You should be able to output your text by doing a simple tree traversal.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [yEd](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html). I'm pretty sure, licensing yFiles just for an API to display tree structures is a bit exaggerated, but the graph editor is free of license costs and you can use it to render your trees. I usually dump my raw graph data in one of the supported file formats, open the output file with yEd and let it do the layout.